# Notation for specifying the fractional part of a number

Tags: notation, fractions, rational-numbers

Just like the title says, what is the notation for specifying the fractional part of a number?

Comment: $x = [x] + \{x \}$, where $[x]$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$, and $\{ x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Tyvm

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fractional part of a number $x$ is usually denoted by $\{x\}$ or $\operatorname{frac}(x)$ (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part)), i.e. $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$, where $\lfloor \cdot\rfloor$ is the floor function.

Comment: Is the result of $\{x\}$ still treated as a fraction or does it become a whole number and could one explicitly state such?

Comment: @BobFischer If we define the fractional part as $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$, then the function $\{\cdot\}$ maps the real numbers to the interval $[0,1)$. The result is $0$ if $x\in\mathbb Z$ and the result belongs to the interval $(0,1)$ if $x\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Z$.

Comment: I forgot to \ the brackets but anyway I think I can just take the inverse since it is a fraction, as in $\{x\}^{-1}$

Comment: If $\{x\}$ is $\frac{1}{0}$, $\{x\}^{-1}$ isn't actually division by zero, $\frac{0}{1}$.

Comment: Because $\{x\}$ must be a fraction and so long as the fraction isn't $\frac{0}{0}, \{x\}^{-1}$ works. And even then it's pretty obvious if the fractional part is zero the whole number should be zero too. Division by zero being undefined doesn't really apply to this case.

Comment: But what about negative numbers? Wouldn't this mean that $\textrm{frac}(-\pi) \approx 0.8584$ rather than 0.14159?

Comment: @RobertSoupe There are conflicting ways to extend fractional part function to negative numbers (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part#For_negative_numbers)).

Answer (score 4):

Braces is a common notation so the fractional part of $x$ would be denoted by $\{x\}$.

That being said, I would rather not use it without explaining it.

Comment: Rational, indeed... as $\{x\}$ would also denote the singleton set containing the element $x$.