# What is meant with $\text{mod }\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: real-analysis

What is meant with $\text{mod }\mathbb{Z}$?

For example what is $2.5\text{ mod }\mathbb{Z}$ and $2\text{ mod }\mathbb{Z}$?

Of Course, I know that for example $4\text{ mod }3=1$ etc.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry if this is a little abstract, but given any group $G$ and normal subgroup $H$ (in your case $G = \mathbb{R}$ and $H = \mathbb{Z}$) one can form the 'quotient group' $G/H$ whose elements are sets formed by taking an element of $G$ and multiplying by all the elements of $H$. In some cases it is standard to refer to this element as '$g \text{ mod } H$'.

In your example $G = \mathbb{R}$ and $H = \mathbb{Z}$ elements of the quotient group are set $[r] = \{r + a : a \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. These elements can then be identified with their unique element in the interval $[0,1)$. It is better in fact to think of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ as a circle, since $0$ and $1$ are identified by making this quotient (imagine the real line wrapping round the circle 'with period 1'). For example 
$$
2.5 \text{ mod }\mathbb{Z} = [2.5] = \{\ldots ,-1.5, -0.5, 0.5 , 1.5 , 2.5 , \ldots \}
$$
which we can identify with $0.5$ if we want.

This example obviously extends the cases you are familiar with when $G = \mathbb{Z}$ and $H = k\mathbb{Z}$ for some integer $k$.

Answer (score 3):

$a \equiv b \pmod{\mathbb{Z}}$ means $a - b \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Equivalently, $a - \lfloor a \rfloor = b - \lfloor b \rfloor$.

If you're regarding "mod" as an operator, then

$$a\text{ mod }{\mathbb{Z}} = a - \lfloor a \rfloor$$

Thus, for the examples you posed,

$$2.5\text{ mod }{\mathbb{Z}} = .5$$

$$2\text{ mod }{\mathbb{Z}} = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

It means that you ignore the integer part so that $a\equiv b\operatorname{mod} \mathbb{Z}$ exactly when $a-b\in\mathbb{Z}$. For example, $2.5\equiv 0.5\operatorname{mod} \mathbb{Z}$ since $2.5-0.5=2\in\mathbb{Z}$, and $2\equiv 0\operatorname{mod} \mathbb{Z}$ since $2-0=2\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing here, but perhaps $$a \mathbin{\mathrm{mod}} \mathbb{Z}$$ means the unique $a' \in [0,1)$ satisfying $a-a' \in \mathbb{Z}$. For example: $$2 \mathbin{\mathrm{mod}} \mathbb{Z} = 0 \qquad 2.5 \mathbin{\mathrm{mod}} \mathbb{Z} = 0.5$$

I'm claiming that $$a \mathbin{\mathrm{mod}} \mathbb{Z} =  a - \lfloor a \rfloor.$$
I don't know if this is actually what the notation means, so please leave a comment if I'm wrong.

Comment: Sometimes, the fractional part is denoted $\{a\}$. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1882055/notation-for-specifying-the-fractional-part-of-a-number.